# QtWebEngine Fetch API fails with custom scheme

Tags: qt, qml, fetch, chromium, qtwebengine

Im trying to create custom schema for [QtWebEngineView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html) with [QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineurlschemehandler.html) to serve web page from local drive. Page is using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to request some json files.

Here is implementation for my custom scheme

**appschemehandler.cpp**

```
AppSchemeHandler::AppSchemeHandler(QObject *parent):
    QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler(parent),
    m_scheme(QWebEngineUrlScheme("app"))
{
    m_scheme.setFlags(
        QWebEngineUrlScheme::SecureScheme |
        QWebEngineUrlScheme::LocalAccessAllowed |
        QWebEngineUrlScheme::ViewSourceAllowed |
        QWebEngineUrlScheme::ContentSecurityPolicyIgnored |
        QWebEngineUrlScheme::CorsEnabled
    );
    QWebEngineUrlScheme::registerScheme(m_scheme);
}

void AppSchemeHandler::install()
{
    QWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile()->installUrlSchemeHandler("app", this);
}

void AppSchemeHandler::requestStarted(QWebEngineUrlRequestJob *job)
{
    ...
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    AppSchemeHandler appSchemeHandler(nullptr);

    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    appSchemeHandler.install();


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));

    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);

    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);


    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
Window {
    id: browser

    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600

    WebEngineView {
        id: webengine

        anchors.fill: parent
        url: 'app://my-app'
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lets Fetch!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lets Fetch!</h1>
    <script>
        fetch("/myFile.json").then(res => console.log(res.json()));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works as it should until web page is trying to `fetch()`. This is what I get to chromium console.
`Fetch API cannot load app://my-app/myFile.json. URL scheme "app" is not supported.`

I made quick test with [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) that provides `protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged()` and there is no problems using Fetch API. So then I inspected electron process args and found `--fetch-schemes=app`. I think that is not Chromium (Blink?) arg since there is no change even if I pass it to my Qt application straight or through `QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS` environment variable.

What is the Qt way of adding custom fetch schemes?

Comment: share the .qml...

Comment: @eyllanesc I updated my question. Its super simple so I don't think its too relevant when dealing with custom schemes.

Comment: Believe it or not, sometimes where it is thought to be simple and mistakes cannot be made, this is the cause of the problem (not necessarily in this case).

Comment: Cant argue with that. Been there kazillion times. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix was integrated into the dev branch and will be available in Qt 6.6. You can then add `QWebEngineUrlScheme::FetchApiAllowed` to the flags and it should work.

```
m_scheme.setFlags(
        QWebEngineUrlScheme::SecureScheme |
        QWebEngineUrlScheme::LocalAccessAllowed |
        QWebEngineUrlScheme::ViewSourceAllowed |
        QWebEngineUrlScheme::ContentSecurityPolicyIgnored |
        QWebEngineUrlScheme::CorsEnabled |
        QWebEngineUrlScheme::FetchApiAllowed
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

Not a proper answer to your question (which seems to be a [known bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-88830)), but a possible workaround:

It seems like `fetch()` works fine with requests that start with a http URL and are then redirected to the custom scheme with a `QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor`. So for your example, do `fetch("http://my-app/myFile.json")` in JavaScript, and then redirect this to `app://my-app/myFile.json` with the interceptor. Unfortunately, that means changing the JavaScript code, but it might be better than nothing.

This is the Python code I used, which should be straightforward to port to C++:

```py
class Interceptor(QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
    def interceptRequest(self, info):
        url = info.requestUrl()
        if url.scheme() != 'http' or url.host() != 'my-app':
            return

        url.setScheme('app')
        info.redirect(url)
```

This interceptor is then installed on the `QWebEngineProfile` with `profile.setUrlRequestInterceptor(interceptor)`.

Comment: This solution does not work.